# What is the difference between SUM and SUBTOTAL?

Tags: excel

In Excel, what is the difference between

SUBTOTAL (9, myrange)

and

SUM (myrange)
?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The big difference between SUBTOTAL and SUM is that SUBTOTAL can be used repeatedly in the same column for section subtotals and then used again at the end for a grand total.  SUBTOTAL(9, myrange) excludes other SUBTOTAL-calculated values within myrange.  SUM does not exclude anything, so if you have section subtotals, and use SUM(myrange) for your grand total, your grand total will be double what it should be (since it has counted the "naked" row values in myrange as well as the section subtotals that lie within myrange).

Comment: Well said.

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2008/01/04/subtotals-ignoring-subtotals/

Answer (score 7):

Subtotal() will exclude subtotal values in set range. On top of that, it also takes filtering into consideration -- it will only sum up shown filtered value from set range

Answer (score -2):

[According to Microsoft, there is no difference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-num-ref1-ref2-HP010062463.aspx), although `SUBTOTAL()` is more flexible since it has the option of including or ignoring hidden values. I wouldn't be surprised if `SUM()` (and others like `AVERAGE()` and `STDEV()`) were implemented in terms of `SUBTOTAL()`.

Comment: -1: A major difference not mentioned in this answer is that SUBTOTAL() doesn't include the result of other SUBTOTAL() calculations in the range. This is actually the overriding reason for using SUBTOTAL() in most cases.

Comment: SUBTOTAL does ignore hidden values especially if using FILTER features